# Ruby popen3 not working as expected in Sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, sidekiq

I'd like to find out more info about the wait_thread being passed to my Popen wrapper method

```
def my_popen(cmd, ignore_err = true)
  Open3.popen3(cmd, {}) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
    cmd_status = wait_thr.value
    cmd_output << stdout.read
    cmd_output << stderr.read unless ignore_err
  end
  return cmd_output, cmd_status
end
```

It works for short running processes but it is being used in a Sidekiq worker which can take around an hour. However when I time it, it takes only around 30 secs every time no matter how long the worker really takes. To time it I just add a timestamp entry into the database at the beginning of the worker and then update it at the end for thread safety and so I can see it in a UI.

Is there something to do with this wait thread that is timing out after around 30 seconds?